# Problem with preg_replace in php - Transform specific codes in html

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to transform this:

```
§f§lWORDHERE
```

in this:

```
<span style="color: white;><b>WORDHERE</b></span>
```

I thought that with this I would achieve it, but apparently it is not like this:

```
<?php

$colorcodes = array(
    '/§f/',
    '/§l/'
);

$replacement = array(
    '<span style="color: white;">$0</span>',
    '<b>$0</b>',
);

$str = "§f§lWORDHERE";

$str_res = preg_replace($colorcodes, $replacement, $str);

echo $str_res;

?>
```

The idea is:

```
§F => white
§L => bold
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Wheres your output?

Comment: @GetSet 

<span style="color: white;">§f</span>
<b>§l</b>
WORDHERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first catch the flags, then replace them:

```
$str = '§f§lWORDHERE';

$replacements = [
  '§f' => '<span style="color: white;">$0</span>',
  '§l' => '<b>$0</b>',
];

if (preg_match('/^(?<flags>(?:§[a-z])+)(?<string>.*)/iu', $str, $matches)) {
    $str_res = $matches['string'];

    foreach (mb_str_split($matches['flags'], 2) as $flag) {
        $str_res = preg_replace('/.+/', $replacements[$flag], $str_res);
    }

    echo $str_res;
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/MC18s)**

Note:

```
mb_str_split($matches['flags'], 2)
```

can be replaced with:

```
str_split($matches['flags'], 3)
```

if you're using PHP < 7.4.

Answer (score -1):

Your regexp is only matching the prefix, not the word after it. You need a capture group for the word.

```
$colorcodes = array(
    '/§f(\w+)/',
    '/§l(\w+)/'
);

$replacement = array(
    '<span style="color: white;">$1</span>',
    '<b>$1</b>',
);
```

Comment: Sorry I left out the `+` in the second one. Didn't you notice the difference?